# Xamarin Android app crash in Release mode (Parse.Android SDK)

Tags: c#, android, linq, xamarin, parse-platform

I am developing app which uses Parse Android SDK. App is working properly in debug mode but when i compile it on release mode i get following errors. Error occur when parse query is executed. Not when i initialize parse.

```
[MonoDroid] UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
[MonoDroid]   at Parse.PlatformHooks+<RequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskActionInvoker+FuncTaskInvoke`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]]].Invoke (System.Threading.Tasks.Task owner, System.Object state, System.Threading.Tasks.Task context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Parse.ParseObject]].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskActionInvoker+FuncTaskInvoke`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Parse.ParseObject]]].Invoke (System.Threading.Tasks.Task owner, System.Object state, System.Threading.Tasks.Task context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Parse.ParseObject]].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[MonoDroid]   at ParseDAL.ParseCaller+<Init>c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono] 
[mono] Unhandled Exception:
[mono] System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
[mono]   at Parse.PlatformHooks+<RequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[mono]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskActionInvoker+FuncTaskInvoke`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]]].Invoke (System.Threading.Tasks.Task owner, System.Object state, System.Threading.Tasks.Task context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono]   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke 
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
[mono-rt]   at Parse.PlatformHooks+<RequestAsync>d__19.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt] --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
[mono-rt]   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at Parse.Internal.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7`1[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]].<OnSuccess>b__6 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskActionInvoker+FuncTaskInvoke`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Tuple`2[System.Net.HttpStatusCode,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]]]].Invoke (System.Threading.Tasks.Task owner, System.Object state, System.Threading.Tasks.Task context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[mono-rt]   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task
```

Following is the code:

```
ParseClient.Initialize("App Id", "Dot Net Key");
var userQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Table Name");
var userData = await userQuery.FindAsync ();
foreach (var ud in userData) {
    Console.WriteLine ("UD " + ud.Get<string>(Constants.COL_USER_NAME));
}
```

I tried with all linker option "Dont Link", "Link All Assemblies", "Link SDK assemblies". But app is still crashing.

Comment: Are there any release mode optimisations you can disable? Perhaps one of those is causing it.

Comment: when i disable optimizations nothing is changed,thanks for the tip doe

Comment: @SeeSharp When i compiled the Backend code DLLs in 'debug' mode and refer them in my front end project then it is working fine, both in release and debug mode.
This exception some times occurs when we have sent the request to server(response pending). and network is disconnected or server is not reachable. I do not know how to handle it, or stop the crash.

Comment: And make sure you have added the "Internet" permission in release mode. In debug mode Internet permission is automatically added in manifest file.

Comment: well i have sent a project to parse support, which recreate this issue. replay was that they will refer the proper team. so still waiting. i will keep you in touch if something new come up

Comment: @ Basit ZIa your idea really works bro THANK YOU

Comment: btw if you wanna post a comment as an answers

Comment: @SeeSharp done, and you are welcome

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This exception occur because of network issue not because of debug/release build. In debug mode INTERNET permission is automatically added in manifest file, but not in release mode.
So add this permission in manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

after this exception will not occur in release mode.

We still need to check that network is available or not before sending request to parse.

Comment: Fantastic! you saved my day

Comment: Works for me too.