# Xamarin Released/Debug apk is not opening on android device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, apk

I have created an app in Xamarin Android and its running fine on emulator,I install the Debug & Released mode apk to a real device,installation done successfully but none of them are opening on device. Its giving me an error "unfortunately app has stopped". What could be the reason ?

I also tired following configuration while building app in release mode:

Packaging:

Use Shared Run time: false(Unchecked)

Use Fast Deployment: false(Unchecked)

Linking : Sdk Assemblies Only

Architecture:   armeabi-v7a

Comment: How are you doing the installation?

Comment: just copied the apk file from folder to device and did the installation.

Comment: You can't run it through on the device from XS or VS so you would see the error message? Or just connect to logcat with adb

Comment: If you deploy or debug from Visual Studio will it crash? (The reason I ask is I saw a similar error myself - in my case I needed to stop using Shared Runtime before I side-loaded, but I can see from your post that you've already tried that - I'm wondering if there's some other similar issue at play like a missing library or something like that). Also, what happens when you try different linking types? Will it still crash? Finally, when it crashes does it leave you with any kind of log at all? I'm wondering if there's any evidence that it's executing any of your code or if it crashes before it.

Comment: Are you signing your `.apk` correctly? You should look at the respective `adb logcat` to see what it says when you attempt to launch the application.

Comment: here what i found in logcat:
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load monodroid from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/AppPOC.AppPOC-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/AppPOC.AppPOC-1, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the issue.I just added the below line of code in the manifest file and it works.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Hope it may help someone else!

Comment: duplicated answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866140/xamarin-android-app-crash-in-release-mode-parse-android-sdk